# Mink - Could not retrieve Microsoft served pages

Tags: mink, goutte, guzzle

I have this code

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../inc/mink.phar');

$url = 'http://some-asp-sites.com/';

// Instantiate Mink's Goutte Driver
$guzzle_client_options = array(
    'curl.options' => array(
        'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => false,
        'CURLOPT_CERTINFO' => false,
        'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' => 120        
    ),
    'ssl.certificate_authority' => 'system'
);

$client = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Goutte\Client();
$client->setClient(new \Guzzle\Http\Client($url, $guzzle_client_options));

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\GoutteDriver($client);

// Initialize Mink
$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// Start session
$session->start();

// Open form page
$session->visit($url);

var_dump($session->getResponseHeaders());
```

And when I try using this code on pages which has part of the response headers as

```
'Server' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0' (length=21)
```

then I get this error

```
<h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr>
<p>HTTP Error 400. The req...an invalid header name.</p>
```

I have repeated this code for PHP served and Microsoft served(I suspect ASP) sites. It is only the ASP sites that has this problem.

Is there any reason why it shouldn't work with Microsoft served pages?

Comment: Aha, I should have searched better [when I had this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180837/goutte-wont-load-an-asp-ssl-page)!